# Why can I pass CHAR[] as a LPSTR parameter?

Tags: c++, winapi

This is working for me...

```
std::string GetProgramDataPath() {

    CHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPathA(nullptr, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, nullptr, 0, path); // path accepted as LPSTR parameter?

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        return std::string(path); // then automatically cast to const char*?
    }
    else {
        return std::string();
    }
}
```

...but I don't know why. I try to pass `LPSTR`, but I get:

> Error C4700 "uninitialized local variable 'path' used"

I look up how to initialize `LPSTR` and come up with this:

```
std::string GetProgramDataPath() {

    LPSTR path = new CHAR[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPathA(nullptr, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, nullptr, 0, path);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        std::string strPath(path);
        delete[] path;
        return std::string(strPath);
    }
    else {
        delete[] path;
        return std::string();
    }
}
```

Is this the 'correct' code? With `new` and `delete` it seems wrong. Am I doing something unsafe by just using `CHAR[]`? How come it works instead of `LPSTR`? I believe it has something to do with the "equivalence of pointers and arrays" in C, but it seems there are some automatic conversions from `CHAR[]` to `LPSTR` to `const char *` in this code I don't understand.

Comment: There is no "equivalence of pointers and arrays". An array can be implicitly converted into a pointer to its first element, and in your first code, `&path[0]` is a `CHAR*`, which (these days) is the same as `LPSTR`. And for any type `T`, `T*` can be implicitly convetred into `const T*`.

Comment: You need to post code that actually produces C4700, "I try to pass LPSTR" is not enough of a hint to guess what you tried.

Comment: Not related to C4710, but you should probably use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` instead of `SHGetFolderPathA`.

Comment: @Lundin If C or C++ had an ABI, then that would be an option. Turns out that neither has, and Windows had to invent it's own. Incidentally, [`LPSTR` **is** a type alias for `char*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), so I wonder what your point is exactly. If you don't like to have an ABI, then by all means, develop for Linux. It never bothered to define one, so you don't have to deal with ABI types.

Comment: LPSTR is a char*, but it also has a SAL annotation on it for inspection tools to denote it as a null terminated string and not just a pointer to a character.

Comment: You **could** allocate and manage the buffer your self, but why not just use a `std::string` instead? `std::string buf(MAX_PATH, '\0');` and then pass `buf.data()` to `SHGetFolderPathA`. You can do the same thing with `std::wstring` if you have `UNICODE` defined and use the `W` version of the function.

Comment: Also, why not take a look at the alias for `LPSTR`, it might help you to understand why you were having issues initially. If you're using Visual Studio it's easy to look at declarations and definitions of stuff

Comment: @HansPassant I just declared `LPSTR path;` without initializing, being a pointer this wont work so the posted code is the best I've found.

Comment: I don't use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` as the result needs to be cast back to `const char *` and this was the simplest way to avoid converting wide string back to narrow, by not using wide string at all. This legacy app only supports ASCII.

Comment: Yes, that is necessary.  How new[] is better than CHAR[] is very hard to guess.

Comment: @WBuck Thanks :) I tried `buf.data()` but I need to append to the string later to get the fullpath to my ProgramData file and this method wouldn't let me, it was limited to the original value returned by `GetProgramDataPath`.

Comment: @DLT The reason is that the `std::string` would contain numerous `null` terminating characters at the end of the buffer.. You could just find the first `null` terminating character in the `std::string` and then `resize` the `std::string` before returning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is working for me...but I don't know why.

`LPSTR` is just an alias for `CHAR*` (aka `char*`):

```
typedef CHAR *LPSTR;
```

In certain contexts, a fixed-sized `CHAR[]` (aka `char[]`) array will *decay* into a `CHAR*` (aka `char*`) pointer to its 1st element, such as when passing the array by value in a function parameter, as you are doing.

> I try to pass `LPSTR`, but I get `Error C4700 "uninitialized local variable 'path' used"`.

Because `LPSTR` is just a pointer, and you likely did not point it at anything meaningful.

> Is this the 'correct' code?

*Technically* yes, that will work (though `return std::string(strPath)` should be `return strPath` instead).  However, you should consider using `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` instead to manage memory for you, don't use `new[]`/`delete[]` directly, eg:

```
std::string GetProgramDataPath() {

    std::vector<char> path(MAX_PATH);
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPathA(nullptr, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, nullptr, 0, path.data());

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        return std::string(path.data());
    }

    return std::string();
}
```

> Am I doing something unsafe by just using `CHAR[]`?

No.

> How come it works instead of `LPSTR`?

Because `CHAR[]` *decays* into the same type that `LPSTR` is an alias of.

> it seems there are some automatic conversions from `CHAR[]` to `LPSTR` to `const char *` in this code.

Correct.

Comment: *"automatic conversions from [...] `LPSTR` to `const char *`"* - That's a possible, implicit conversion, but it's not being exercised here. `SHGetFolderPathA` requires a mutable buffer, aka `char*`.

Comment: @IInspectable `SHGetFolderPathA()` takes a `char*`, yes, but the `std::string` constructor takes a `const char*`, and that is also being used.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of managing the memory your self with `new` and `delete` I'd use a `std::string` instead and let it manage the memory.

```
static std::string GetProgramDataPath()
{
    std::string buffer(MAX_PATH, '\0');
    const HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPathA
    (
        nullptr, 
        CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, 
        nullptr, 
        0, 
        buffer.data()
     );

     if (SUCCEEDED(result))
     {
         // Cut off the trailing null terminating characters.
         // Doing this will allow you to append to the string
         // in the position that you'd expect.
         if (const auto pos{ buffer.find_first_of('\0') }; pos != std::string::npos)
             buffer.resize(pos);

         // Here is how you can append to the string further.
         buffer.append(R"(\Some\Other\Directory)");
         return buffer;
     }

     buffer.clear();
     return buffer;
}
```

Here is one way you could do it using `std::filesystem::path` and `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

static fs::path GetProgramDataPath()
{
    struct buffer {
        wchar_t* data{ nullptr };
        ~buffer() { CoTaskMemFree(data); }
    } buf{};

    const HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath
    (
        FOLDERID_ProgramData,
        0, 
        nullptr, 
        &buf.data
    );

    return SUCCEEDED(result) 
        ? fs::path{ buf.data } 
        : fs::path{};
}

int main()
{
    fs::path path{ GetProgramDataPath() };
    
    if (!path.empty())
    {
        // Here is one way you can append to a path.
        // You can also use the append member function as well.
        path /= R"(Some\Other\Directory)";

        // When you're ready you can call either the generic_string or
        // string member function on the path.
        const std::string s1{ path.string() };
        const std::string s2{ path.generic_string() };
    
        // Prints: 'C:\ProgramData\Some\Other\Directory'.
        std::cout << s1 << '\n';

        // Prints: 'C:/ProgramData/Some/Other/Directory'.
        std::cout << s2 << '\n';
    }    
}
```

Comment: Since this example is using modern C++ features that require at least C++17, I would take it a step further and have the function return `std::filesystem::path` instead of `std::string`. That doesn't change how the code retrieves data from `SHGetFolderPath()`, but it does make the return value more flexible for the caller to use, especially when manipulating the path afterwards to create other paths.

Comment: *"That doesn't change how the code retrieves data from `SHGetFolderPath()`"* - Actually, that's the part that *should* change. Calling `SHGetFolderPathA` (as opposed to `SHGetFolderPathW`) is literally always wrong. Not that that matters much if you subscribe to calling an API that would limit itself to `MAX_PATH` characters, a limit that hadn't been a thing for decades...

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's funny I **was** going to do that but stopped myself. These days I try not to veer to far off of the OP's code snippet. But I agree with you 100%.

Comment: @IInspectable Couldn't agree more. I didn't use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` for two reasons. First the OP mentioned in the comments that they didn't want the hassle of converting the wide character set to narrow. The second reason was that I didn't want to also show an example of `WideCharToMultiByte` to make the example complete when the OP expressed that they weren't interested.

Comment: @WBuck if the OP switched from `std::string` to `std::filesystem::path`, then they could use wide characters and not convert them to narrow.

Comment: @IInspectable "*a limit that hadn't been a thing for decades...*" - MS's file system APIs have been limited to `MAX_PATH` for decades, unless you explicitly use the ```\\?\``` prefix (which most people don't) or you explicitly opt in to long paths in Windows 10 v1607+ only.

Comment: @RemyLebeau *"which most people don't"* - Well, ugh, citation needed, I guess? If you do find data that supports your statement, then maybe that's because some folks approach questions like *"Hey, so I want to use an API that's **explicitly** marked as deprecated, and don't give a rats ass about character encodings either"* with [*"There you go"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75328962/1889329) (no warnings, notes, rationale)?

Comment: The codebase dates back decades, assumes only ASCII characters and no unicode. It’s a massive undertaking to change that.. If there are ways to future proof with `SHGetFolderPath` and `std::filesystem::path` without introducing additional code or complexity I'm interested. Howver, this question was to further my understanding on the code as posted, as I'll be dealing with a lot of legacy code.

Comment: @DLT Sure, I showed a quick example of using the `std::filesystem::path`.